# Encrypting .aws/crendentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am trying to encrypt AWS credentials on AWS CLI. I want to have my access_key and access_id not readable.

I have tried: aws kms encrypt --key-id  --plaintext fileb:///.aws/credentials but I can still view content in plaintext

Any Ideas?

Comment: If you are concerned about storing long lived credentials, you can configure aws cli  with aws sso - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-sso.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do what you are trying to do.  AWS needs your credentials to be clear-text.

If this is your local machine and you are uncomfortable with having your credentials in your .aws/credentials file, try using a tool like [aws-vault](https://github.com/99designs/aws-vault).

It will store your credentials in your operating systems local keystore and require you to enter a password when you want to use your credentials.